# problem when trying to setup simple_captcha in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby(1.9) on Rails(2.3.4) app that I'm currently developing. I want to add Captcha to it and I ran across Simple_Captcha plugin which installs fine but when I try the setup command for it (rake simple_captcha) I give the error below

Note: I use rake19 because I have two versions of Ruby (1.9 and 1.8.6 installed) I run ruby 1.9 command by adding the 19 e.g. gem19 ruby19 rake19..etc

```
Macintosh-10:wisf tam$ sudo rake19 simple_captcha:setup --trace
Password:
(in /Users/tammam56/rubydev/wisf)
** Invoke simple_captcha:setup (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute simple_captcha:setup
STEP 1
===============================================================================
ruby script/generate migration create_simple_captcha_data
/Users/tammam56/rubydev/wisf/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
 from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/wisf/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:1
 from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/wisf/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:1:in `require'
 from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/wisf/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:1
 from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/wisf/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:10:in `require'
 from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/wisf/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:10
 from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/wisf/config/boot.rb:45:in `require'
 from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/wisf/config/boot.rb:45:in `load_initializer'
 from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/wisf/config/boot.rb:38:in `run'
 from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/wisf/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
 from /Users/tammam56/rubydev/wisf/config/boot.rb:110
 from script/generate:2:in `require'
 from script/generate:2

================================DONE===========================================
#<TypeError: can't convert nil into String>
```

any ideas?

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned - *I run ruby 1.9 command by adding the 19 e.g. gem19 ruby19 rake19..etc*

What is the version number showing up on your terminal when you run  `ruby -v`

From the error you've given in your post, the script is attempting to run

`ruby script/generate migration create_simple_captcha_data`

based on your comments it should look like

`ruby19 script/generate migration create_simple_captcha_data`

HTH

Comment: Thanks Anand. Good call..That led me to the solution, it was hard-coded inside the installation files to use "ruby" command. Thanks :)